# Get a list of classes derived from given base class in Perl

Tags: perl, oop

Given a base class and a list of classes derived from it:

```
package base
{
    # ...
}

package foo
{
    our @ISA = 'base';
    # ...
}

package bar
{
    our @ISA = 'base';
    # ...
}
```

**Is there a runtime way to get a list of classes which have `base` as parent?**

I know I could easily work around this by adding their names to a list manually, but I was wondering if `base` itself could tell me who inherited from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Perl 5.10, Perl has come with a module called `mro` which includes a whole bunch of functions for inspecting class hierarchies.

You can find child classes of `My::Class` using:

```perl
use mro;

my $base_class = 'My::Class';
print "$_\n" for @{ mro::get_isarev( $base_class ) };
```

The `mro` documentation includes various caveats, such as the fact that calling it on the `'UNIVERSAL'` package doesn't work properly. There will be other cases it copes badly with, but if you're "doing normal stuff", it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the names of all the "potential" classes, you can recursively iterate through the complete "namespace".

```
sub inspect {
    my ($package, $search_for) = @_;
    my @result;
    my $keys = 'sort keys (%' . $package . '::)';
    $package=~ s/main:://;
    my @keys = eval $keys;
    foreach my $lookup (@keys) {
        $lookup =~ s/main:://;
        if ($lookup =~ /(.*)::$/) {
            push @result, inspect($package.'::'.$1, $search_for);
        }
    }
    push @result, $package
         if $package->isa($search_for);
    return @result;
}
```

so in your example:

```
print "Number of derived classes: " . (inspect('main', 'base') -1) .  "\n";
```

we have to extract one, as the class is an instance of its own.

AFAIK base doesn't store the "class-tree" anywhere.

Comment: Re "*AFAIK base doesn't store the "class-tree" anywhere.*", This is not stored in the base module, no. (And if you're referring to base.pm -- which isn't used here -- then it doesn't either)

Comment: This suffers from a code injection bug. But it's very unlikely to cause harm, intentionally or otherwise. (Packages with very weird names can be created.) I actually upvoted despite this, though I did post an alternate approach of doing the same thing which doesn't suffer from the code injection bug (and which is clearer in my opinion).

Comment: @ikegami You mean the `my $keys = 'sort keys (%' . $package . '::)';  my @keys = eval $keys;`. One could, of course, check $package, but I tried to write that code without an eval and didn't find a way to. Do you have an idea?

Comment: You'd use `%::` or `my $pkg_ref = do { no strict 'refs'; \%{ $package . '::' } }; %$pkg_ref`. My answer used `%::`, but I deleted it because the now-accepted answer is better.

Comment: Thx for pointing this out. Using `no strict 'refs';` in a block to avoid using eval is a suitable solution here. %:: is an alias for %main:: AFAIK. `perl -e 'print \%:: eq \%main::'` prints out '1'

Comment: `*::` and `*main::` and `*main::main::` and `*main::main::main::` are the same namespace, so `%::`, `%main::`, `%main::main::` and `%main::main::main::` are the same var, yes. I don't see the point of adding those any "main", especially when I mean the root.

Comment: Using 'main' makes this more readable to me. Maybe it's my educational background from the 80's.

Comment: I don't use `$main::Foo::Bar::var` to refer to `$Foo::Bar::var`. Same idea here.